# convert associate array to XML in php

Tags: php, xml, associative-array

How do i convert an associate array to an XML string? I [found this](http://snipplr.com/view/3491/convert-php-array-to-xml-or-simple-xml-object-if-you-wish/) but get the error 'Call to a member function addChild() on a non-object' when running the line

```
$node = $xml->addChild($key);
```

Comment: Can you provide the code including your calls to the provided `ArrayToXML::toXML()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the PHP [Document Object Model](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php):

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$root = $xml->createElement('top');
$xml->appendChild($root);
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
  $node = $xml->createelement($k);
  $text = $xml->createTextNode($v);
  $node->appendChild($text);
  $root->appendChild($node);
}
echo $xml->saveXml();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize the $xml object? That's probably your problem.

Comment: How? when i saw =null i thought it wasnt required

Comment: it says you are making a call on a non-object. That means the object does not exist. if it's null, how can it have a method?

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty similar to how you would do something like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

You can't use $result as an array, but you can foreach or while through the different entries.

Answer (score 0):

PEAR's XML_Serialize is pretty good if you want a easy solution.  Doing the DOM manually is arguably faster.